# Как мне изменить число на странице сайта на диапазон чисел?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте есть блок "Сколько сейчас людей онлайн". Как мне сделать на JS или jQuery замену этого текста и показывать число рандомно от 1500 до 2000. Делать за меня не надо просто дайте направление. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Генерируем случайное целое число от `1500` до `2000`.
- Выбираем нужный элемент на странице по селектору и устанавливаем ему полученное число в качестве текста.

```js
$(function() {
    var min = 1500;
    var max = 2000;
    var online = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    $('#online').text(online);
});
```

```html
Сейчас <span id="online"></span> людей онлайн

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Функция `Math.random()` имеет один недостаток: она слишком случайна! : )

Пользователь перезагрузивший страницу может удивиться резким скачкам числа посетителей, а открыв сразу 2-3 таба с этим сайтом легко увидит разные результаты.

Поэтому предложу решение из области motion graphics / анимации. Число посетителей пусть будет функцией времени (оно у всех одно), меняющейся случайно, но не слишком резко. Подойдёт и сумма нескольких периодических функций - несколько синусоид разной амплитуды и периода. Интереснее сделать на основе [шума Перлина](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D1%83%D0%BC_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0). Значение будет случайно, будет меняться, но не резко, и у всех посетителей сайта одинаково.

**upd.** [статья на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/142592/) про шум Перлина.